# Error in assignment using IF-Else Prolog

Tags: prolog

This is part of my code where I am using if else-

```
   foo(4,Lines,A) :-
    ....
    .....
1.   ( (X1\=X2) ->write ('Bye')

2.   ; (X1 = X2,X3=X4,N\=4) ->write('Hello'),nl,D is A + 4,write(D),
         foo(4,lines,D)
3.   ).
```

So this is printing Hello in line2 but then it gives an error.It is not printing value of D.THis is the error I get-

```
ERROR: at_end_of_stream/1: stream `<stream>(000000000894F470)' does not exist
```

So is there something wrong with `D is A + 4` in line 2 because that is what is giving the error???

Comment: It really seems like you're trying to use Prolog in a procedural way. That's simply not the way Prolog is intended to be used. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Well actually this is part of much larger code and in line 2 I want to update the value of D to A+4. This is my first instance of D in the whole program whereas all others like X1,X2.. are defined earlier in the rest of the code.

Comment: Well, `D` can't be "updated". You're doing it wrong :-) You have to think in terms of what you want to be true and what you want to be false. If you describe the signature of your predicate and when you want it to hold, I can help you from there.

Comment: Well my predicate is foo(4,Lines,A) and in line no 2 I want to call it again with new value of A ie A+4.So I am doing D=A+4 and then calling the foo.I have updated my code in the question and described what i want to do.

Comment: Answer this: When should foo be true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really think there was anything wrong with your code. The only error was at `write ('Bye')` where you had a space and I removed it. Maybe there is something wrong with the value of `D`. See this,it works for me:

```
foo(4,Lines,A):- /*read(X1),read(X2),read(X3),read(X4),read(A),read(N),*/
                 ((X1\=X2) -> write('Bye');
                 (X1 = X2,X3=X4,N\=4) -> write('Hello'),nl,D is A + 4,write(D),
                 foo(4,lines,D)).
```

I added the `read/1` so I can test the code. It works for me. This is what I get:

```
3 ?- foo(4,Lines,A).
|: 1. /*read(X1)*/
|: 1. /*read(X2)*/
|: 2. /*read(X3)*/
|: 2. /*read(X4)*/
|: 3. /*read(A)*/
|: 3. /*read(N)*/
Hello
7
|: 1.
|: 1.
|: 2.
|: 2.
|: 3.
false.
```

After the `Hello 7`, the rule `foo/3` runs again. I expect that you'll do something else then, but I cannot see what, so that was my result.

For more info about the error you got ([`at_end_of_stream`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=at_end_of_stream/1)) check the link.

> Succeeds after the last character of the named stream is read, or Stream is not a valid input stream. The end-of-stream test is only available on buffered input streams (unbuffered input streams are rarely used; see open/4).